# How to create Dock icon option for Mac application on Mac OSx?

Tags: macos

On Mac, iTune application have dock menu option. i.e. after right clicking iTune Dock icon, we get options such as Repeat/Shuffle etc. How to create such option for any Mac application? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/intro/dockintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH1-TP1

Comment: I went through the documentaton  developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual//.. but it didnt help me.